# Convert if condition into ternary with C#

Tags: c#, ternary

I would like to use ternary operator in order to factorize if condition.

I know the process : `condition ? consequent : alternative`

I have the if condition following :

```
if (!myField.IsNullOrNa())
    {
        messageErreur += myField.IsDecimalWithMessage(nameof(myField));
    }
```

I would like to write :

```
 messageErreur += !myField.IsNullOrNa() ? myField.IsDecimalWithMessage(nameof(myField)) :
```

What I have to write as alternative ?

Comment: `string.Empty`?

Comment: Why? It's readable and does what's expected. You can write it in a single line, if that's what this is.

Comment: What is the type of `messageErreur`? `String` is suggestive, but it is not totally clear.

Comment: IsNullOrNa? I have never seen this

Comment: @oerkelens I will try and I will go back if it's good

Comment: @Fildor Because I have 10 fields like this. So it's most readable with ternary operator to my mind

Comment: @Codor It's a string yes you're right

Comment: @monstertjie_za Just a method which let to know if field is blank, null etc ..

Comment: _"Because I have 10 fields like this"_ in that case, I'd suggest making that a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have multiple fields to check, simply make a small helper method that returns a string (or empty) based on a condition (boolean):

```
messageErreur += Check(!myField.IsNullOrNa(), myField.IsDecimalWithMessage(nameof(myField)); 
messageErreur += Check(myField.HasError(), myField.HasError(nameof(myField)); 

private string Check(bool condition, string message) => condition ? message : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the value only if the condition is true (and don't change if not), add nothing as 'alternative' part:

```
messageErreur = !myField.IsNullOrNa() ? messageErreur + myField.IsDecimalWithMessage(nameof(myField)) : messageErreur;
```

Comment: why not stay with the `+=` and simply add `string.Empty`? You have added two extra pieces of code (`messageErreur`) to an already long line, without clear benefit.

Comment: @oerkelens: I was not sure about the type of either "messageErreur" and "IsDecimalWithMessage" method. My code works regardless of the type of messageErreur.